# Exponential change and probability

Tags: probability, exponential-function

The question under that topic is:

> A particular bacteria has a 20% chance of surviving 1 h in water with
> chlorine in it? What is the decay rate and how long it takes to bring
> a population of 50,000 to 1?

My attempt:
So if bacteria have a 20% chance of survival, 80% are wiped out per hour. That means that the decay rate r = 0.8.

So $$p(t) = Ne^{-rt}$$
$$\frac{ln(\frac{1}{50000})}{-0.8}=t=13.5 h$$

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: Hint: What is $r$ in this case? If you just forget about the first equation, the more natural way to build the equation is to write
$$
n(t) = n_0 \cdot 0.8^t
$$
This means that the number of bacteria at time $t$ is the initial number, times 0.8 to the power of $t$, the number of hours. Now we should convert (if we want - it's not mandatory) this to the form
$$
N e^{-rt}
$$ ... We should also remember that
$$
a^b = e^{b \cdot \ln a}
$$

Comment: @MattiP. $$r$$ is the decay rate;  the number of decay per unit time.

Comment: hmmm I think you should have $r= \ln(0.8)$ instead of $r=0.8$. That's because the equation that you're using has $e$ in there ...

Comment: @thank you for your response. I am a bit confused about why we have to use r = ln(0.8). Would not this change the exponential decay equation? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay

Comment: This is easier to understand by a simple example: Let's say that you have a radioactive material with a half-life of exactly one second. That means that the quantity halves every second. If you start with the amount $N$, then after $t$ seconds you definitely have only
$$
N \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^t = N \cdot 2^{-t}
$$
of the material, right? That's just logical, no theory needed for that. But now we want to convert this into the form
$$
N \cdot e^{\text{something}}
$$
where $e$ is Euler's number ... We can rewrite
$$
2^{-t} = e^{-t \cdot \ln 2}
$$
Does this help?

Comment: now it is much more clear @MattiP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the general equation to calculate the decay rate. Go step by step. $$p(t) = Ne^{-rt},$$

where $N=p(0)$

You are given that $p(1)=0.2\cdot p(0)$. After one hour, there exist $20\%$ of the initial population. Inserting the values

$$0.2\cdot p(0) = p(0)\cdot e^{-r\cdot 1}$$

$$0.2=  e^{-r}$$

Taking logs

$$\ln(0.2)=  -r\Rightarrow r=-\ln(0.2)$$

Thus $p(t)=p(0)\cdot e^{\ln(0.2)\cdot t}$. Now you can use that $\large{a^{b\cdot c}=\left(a^{b}\right)^c}$

$$p(t)=p(0)\cdot e^{\ln(0.2)\cdot t}=p(0)\cdot \left(e^{\ln(0.2)}\right)^t=p(0)\cdot 0.2^t$$

The same result can be obtained by using the equation $p(t)=p(0)\cdot a^t$.

Comment: > You are given that $p(1)=0.8⋅p(0)$

Sorry, but isn't it  $p(1)=0.2⋅p(0)$

?

Comment: @tommik No sorry. I´ve taken the numbers at the question and at the comments. Thanks for your comment

Comment: I understand why the decay rate, r, is $-ln(0.2)$ by the above calculations, it makes total sense. However, I am slightly confused about why r is NOT -0.8, because each time the population reduces by 80%.

Comment: @Mhf Yes, the population reduces by 80%. That´s true. That means that after one our the population is $100\%-\underbrace{80\%}_{\textrm{reduction}}=20\%$